# how to use map::find on map of maps

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue making some unit tests in a large code base. Basically I need to find a value in map of maps. I wrote a code snippet to explain what my problem is. The following represents how the data is build:

```
map<string, map<string, string>> testmap;
map<string, string> item;
item.insert(pair<string,string>("hello","world"));
testmap.insert(pair<string, map<string,string> > ("key",item));
```

then, at some later point, I need to check that the values have been added before obtaining a key. From the cppreference, the return of the [] operator is

> Reference to the mapped value of the new element if no element with
>   key key existed. Otherwise a reference to the mapped value of the
>   existing element whose key is equivalent to key.

If I understand correctly, which from the comments is clear that I am not, this means that a new element is inserted if there was no element with that key. I want to avoid that, and return an error message.

The following is **wrong** and I'm trying to understand why:

```
if (testmap.find(map<string,string>("hello","world")) != testmap.end()) 
{
    ...
    return testmap["hello"]["world"];
}
```

Comment: `map.find` is used to find keys, not values.

Comment: _I need to find a key in map of maps._ Do you need to find a key or a value? You write the former but do the latter in your code. Please, specify.

Comment: You either need to use `testmap.find("key")` or use `testmap.count`

Comment: Still confusing, "world" is a value in the first code segemnt, but a key in the second segment. "hello" is a key in the inner map in the first segment but a key in the outer map in the second segment. Please be clear what you are really trying to do, with an example that actually works.

Comment: When you telling us that you want to "find value in map", first thing you should consider is if you really decided on correct key for map? May be swap key and values?

Comment: Edit the misleading title. It seems like what you are trying to achieve is finding a specific map inside `testmap`.

Comment: `["hello"]["world"]` "hello" is the key in the inside map and `world` is the value in the inside map. You could `return testmap["key"]["hello"]` and it would return `"world"`. To lookup key by value, ie. to find `"key"` using `map<string, string>({"hello", "world"})` you have traverse the map, like ex. [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1206831.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find a value in a map, you cannot use `find` member function, which finds a key. However, you can find a value, e.g., by using `std::find_if` with a custom comparator:

```
using value_t = std::map<std::string, std::string>;
using key_t = std::string;
using map_t = std::map<key_t, value_t>;

map_t m { { "key" , { { "hello", "world" } } } };

value_t v { { "hello", "world" } };  // value to be found
auto iter = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(),
               [&v](const auto& e){ return e.second == v; });
std::cout << (iter != m.end()) << std::endl;
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/1b0bjbnnPY8E0uiU

---

Note that this will work since C++14. In C++11, you need to write:

```
auto iter = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(),
               [&v](const map_t::value_type& e){ return e.second == v; });
```

**UPDATE**

It's still kind-of unclear to me what you are trying to achieve. If you need a reference to the inner-most value only if it's both-level keys exist, then you can do (C++17 syntax):

```
if (auto i1 = m.find("key"); i1 != m.end())
   if (auto i2 = i1->second.find("hello"); i2 != i1->second.end())
      std::cout << i2->second << std::endl;  // same as m["key"]["hello"] here but faster
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you want is `testmap.find("key")`, i.e. search for key, but for some reason you think that you should search for value...

Comment: Honest answer: The code I'm working on is long and hard to understand. I wrote a snippet of what I thought the code was doing. After all the comments about how confusing the question is, I'm taking a look a the code again because evidently I don't understand the code as well as I thought.

Comment: @cauchy I think that, first of all, you don't understand how maps work. According to your `return` statement, your outer map would need to have an entry with `"hello"` as a key. This entry's value (inner map) then would need to have an entry with `"world"` as a key. But in your constructed map of maps, this does not hold. There, your outer map has an entry with `"key"` key, and it's value (inner) map has an entry with `"hello"` key. I would recommend to draw a chart on the paper to understand this.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for pointing this out and not just give a minus point, which is not helpfull. I looked up how map works and I was wrong. Thanks for your time! This was really helpfull.